# Connecting AngularJS to Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am a beginner in developing with phonegap. For about 12 hours I have been trying to connect an AngularJS application with phonegap, in order to develope a mobile app for android. Unfrotunately, AngularJS does not seem to work for me. [This is a link to my github repository](https://github.com/BoyanH/PhonegapPlusAngularJS/tree/master/www), where I have pushed all the code from the `www` folder of the phonegap project. Basically I have everything linked to my index.html file, routes and controllers seem to look ok. I have done several angular.js applications before, but always with node.js, so this thing is really new for me. Sorry for posting the whole project, but I have been working on this long enough to have absolutely no idea where the problem is. I really tried everything I could...

Comment: Have a look to the ionic framework, it uses angularJS out of the box, it is very convenient. I am using it with cordova and it is a breeze.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angularjs is definitely the best framework which gives us the facility to develop client application using great MVC framework. 
Here is some links i have referred while i was developing phonegap app using angularjs first time.

- [divgirl 2013](http://devgirl.org/2013/06/10/quick-start-guide-phonegap-and-angularjs/)
- [divgirl 2014](http://devgirl.org/2014/05/13/sample-phonegap-application-with-angularjsonsenui/)
- [coenraets 2013](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/11/sample-mobile-application-with-angularjs/)
- [coenraets 2014](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/02/sample-mobile-application-with-ionic-and-angularjs/)

These are the best for reference if you are talking about phonegap & angularjs

Comment: Thanks, I accept your answer as the real answer to the question won't really help anyone. Basicly I have used the variable 'app' for my angular.js app, and so was it called for phonegap in order to run 'app.initialize' and both were intefering.

Basically for phonegap+angular.js you simply generate your phonegap project using cordova, which is easily installed using the node package manager and then you generate an angular app (really easy with yeoman) in the www folder and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing a few days ago and I found this grunt project:
https://github.com/dsimard/grunt-angular-phonegap

I am assuming you have:

1. installed phonegap, generator-angular, grunt
2. made a phonegap project
3. added angular in your project by doing 'yo angular'
4. did a 'cordova platform add android'

Here is what you need to do next:

1. npm install grunt-angular-phonegap --save-dev
2. npm install (both 1. and 2. should be done once inside project directory)
3. grunt phonegap:check
   (it checks if it can build in your system.
   checkAdb will probably fail if you are using windows but you don't have to worry about that)
4. grunt phonegap:build

P.S.the regular command is grunt phonegap:command[:platform] but by default it does android.

That's it.

Thanks to https://github.com/dsimard for the awesome tool.